# PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.edge.le.domain.Tag

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a `Goal` entity which has many to many relationship with `Tag`. Here `Goal` is my owning entity. I am using JPA to persist. Its giving `PersistentObjectException` when I am saving `Goal` with an existing `Tag`. Other scenarios like New `Gaol` wih new `Tag` , editing existing `Goal` with existing `Tag` , existing `Goal` with new `Tag` are working fine . below is my Entity structure:

### Goal.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "goal")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "goal")
public class Goal implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {
         CascadeType.MERGE,
         CascadeType.PERSIST,
    },targetEntity = Tag.class)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@JoinTable(name = "goal_tag",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="goals_id",      referencedColumnName="ID"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="tags_id", referencedColumnName="ID"))
private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

 //getters &  setters
```

### Tag.java

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "tag")
 @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
 @Document(indexName = "tag")
 public class Tag implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private String id;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<Goal> goals = new HashSet<>();

 //getters & setters
```

### GoaServiceImpl.java save() methos

```
 public class GoalServiceImpl implements GoalService{

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoalServiceImpl.class);

@Inject
private GoalRepository goalRepository;

@Inject
private GoalMapper goalMapper;

@Inject
private GoalSearchRepository goalSearchRepository;

@Inject
private TagRepository tagRepository;

/**
 * Save a goal.
 *
 * @param goalDTO the entity to save
 * @return the persisted entity
 */
  public GoalDTO save(GoalDTO goalDTO) {
    log.debug("Request to save Goal : {}", goalDTO);
    Goal goal = goalMapper.goalDTOToGoal(goalDTO);
    goal = goalRepository.save(goal);
    GoalDTO result = goalMapper.goalToGoalDTO(goal);
    //goalSearchRepository.save(goal);
    return result;
}
```

}
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to use `save`, the operation that the persistence provider tries to cascade is `PERSIST`. And when you try to persist an already existing entity that is detached, you end up with that exception.

As you have the MERGE cascade option set on that relationship i would suggest using merge instead of persist:

```
goal = goalRepository.merge(goal);
```

Now, if your goal is a new entity, it will be persisted and detached Tag entities will be merged (and updated if persistence provider spotted a change in state).

Comment: I am using JpaRepository.

public interface GoalRepository extends JpaRepository<Goal,Long> {}

and it doest not have a merge method .

But I used merge() method of EntityManager directly . Is this the right way or some other way is there?

Comment: Well in theory the framework should check whether the entity is new and if not call merge instead of save. This is not the first time that this does not work for some reason.. So i would suggest creating your own custom repository where you would hold the merge method among others. So the baseline is that dont inject the entity manager into your service.. inject it into the repository and then inject the repository into the service